# v.clean with rmarea and lat-long projection

Tags: grass-gis

The [documentation for v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.clean.html) in GRASS 7 says of tool `rmarea` (which absorbs polygons below a certain area into a larger neighbour):

```
Threshold must always be in square meters, also for latitude-longitude
locations or locations with units other than meters.
```

I have a location in EPSG:4283 (GDA94). Running v.clean with the `rmarea` option prints the following warning to the console:

```
Note: In latitude-longitude coordinate system specify threshold in degree
unit
```

These warnings contradict each other. Which is correct? I've been getting the same results on my test dataset using threshold 2500 (assuming square meters) and threshold 0.00000025 (assuming 'square decimal degrees' which I know is dodgy). In both cases, small polygons do disappear, but so do a number of larger ones that shouldn't be caught by either threshold.

**edit:**

I've traced back through the source code: [vector/v.clean/main.c line 438](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/vector/v.clean/main.c) calls `Vect_remove_small_areas`, which lives in [lib/vector/vlib/remove_areas.c](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/lib/vector/Vlib/remove_areas.c). For a native GRASS-format dataset that uses `Vect_remove_small_areas_nat`, which on line 240 calls `Vect_get_area_area`, which lives in [lib/vector/vlib/area.c](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/lib/vector/Vlib/area.c). That function in turn uses `G_area_of_polygon`, which lives in [lib/gis/area.c](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/lib/gis/area.c). That in turn calls `G_ellipsoid_polygon_area` for lat-long data. That function is in [lib/gis/area_poly1.c](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/lib/gis/area_poly1.c) and does the actual calculation (cripes!).

The documentation for that last function indicates that a threshold in meters is fine. This means my real question is why v.clean is removing polygons that it shouldn't. All I could think of is that some vertices might be too close together for the math in `G_ellipsoid_polygon_area` to work, as there are comments in the code referencing that as an issue. I can't see any obvious candidates in my data, though. Are there any other possible confounding factors I'm missing?

Comment: I have opened a ticket for this issue: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3430

Comment: Can you please provide (also privately) a test dataset? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reprojecting your input layer to a UTM projection? Those seem to work for me.